# XML format for a XSLT sheet

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xslt in this format. I need help in figuring out in what format should xml be returned from stored proc which will fit in this xslt.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Type">
    <tr class="{$css-class}">
        <xsl:attribute name ="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="./@TypeID"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <td class="TypeID">
        <xsl:value-of select="./@TypeID"/>
        </td>
        <td class="TypeName">
        <xsl:value-of select="./@TypeName"/>
        </td>
        <td>
        <a title="Edit" href="#EditTypeModal" data-toggle="modal" onclick="editTypeonClick($(this))">
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="./@TypeID"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
        </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

So far, I have tried to return xml in the following format, but it is not working. Please advise what am I missing.

```
<DATA>
    <Type id="1" TypeID="1" TypeName="abc" />
    <Type id="2" TypeID="2" TypeName="def" />
    <Type id="3" TypeID="3" TypeName="xys" />
</DATA>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to figure out how the source XML **should** be structured, instead of adapting the XSLT to whatever structure the XML **is** (and to the desired structure of the output)? -- In any case, we cannot answer your question without seeing the **entire** XSLT, as well as the expected output.

Comment: Actually, we have a situation. The stored proc and some of the database objects have been accidentally dropped and we have to reverse engineer. I can provide the whole xslt if that would help

Comment: In any case, we cannot answer your question without seeing the entire XSLT, as well as the expected output.

Comment: When you say it is "not working", what do you mean? Your XSLT code will produce some output with that input, assuming the DATA element is the context item at the point where it is executed. If that's not good enough, more information is needed.